# Random Ranks Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Peter draws $n = 100$ independent realizations of a continuous *rv* and ranks
them in increasing order from $1$ to $100$. Subsequently, Paula draws a single
value from the same population and inserts this value into the rank order
created earlier by Peter. For example, if her value is such that $50$ of Peter’s
draws are smaller and $50$ are larger, then the rank associated with her draw
would be $51$ that is, overall, her value would be the $51$st in increasing order. Or, if her value is smaller than all $100$ of Peter’s, then the rank $1$ would be associated with it.

Is it more likely that Paula’s value will occupy rank $51$ than rank $1$?

---

**I solve this problem in this manner:**

Let Peter's values in increasing order be $\sigma_{Peter}=\{X_{1},...,X_{100}\}$ and Paula's value be $Y$.

- $P\{\text{Paula’s value occupy rank 1} \} = P\{Y \leq min(\sigma_{Peter})\} = P\{Y\leq X_{1} \cap ...\cap Y\leq X_{100}\} = P\{Y\leq X_{1}\}\times ...\times P\{Y\leq X_{100}\} = (\frac{1}{2})^{100}$
- $P\{\text{Paula’s value occupy rank 50} \} = P\Big\{max\big(\{X_{1},...,X_{50}\}\big) \leq Y \cap Y \leq min\big(\{X_{51},...,X_{100}\}\big)\Big\} = P\{X_{1} \leq Y \cap ... X_{50} \leq Y \cap Y\leq X_{51} \cap ... Y \leq X_{100}\} = P\{X_{1} \leq Y\}\times ...\times P\{X_{50} \leq Y\} \times P\{Y \leq X_{51} \}\times ... \times P\{Y\leq X_{100}\} = (\frac{1}{2})^{100}$

---

According to above computation, rank $51$ and rank $1$ have a same probability.

---

***My Question:*** The above computation is wrong. Where is it wrong?

Comment: The distribution of $X_i$ (the rank $i$ realization of Peter) does not have the same distribution as the original random variable (e.g. $Y$). For example, $X_1$ will be more likely to be pretty small, compared to the original random variable.

Comment: Moreover, the events $\{Y \le X_i\}$ are not independent, since $\{Y \le X_i\}$ implies $\{Y \le X_{i+1}\}$.

Comment: The $101$ draws are i.i.d., so in particular they are exchangeable. I believe this implies that the $101$st draw is equally likely to be any rank from $1$ to $101$.

Comment: Another point of view: Using probability integral transform (which preserve the order) will obtain ordered uniform (which we know has a beta distribution). Then, $\displaystyle \Pr\{U_{k} < U < U_{k+1}\} = E[\Pr\{U_{k} < U < U_{k+1}|U_{k}, U_{k+1}\}] = E[U_{k+1} - U_{k}] = \frac {k+1} {n+1} - \frac {k} {n+1} = \frac {1} {n+1}$ which is independent of the rank $k$. So this also support the comment by angryavian that with an iid sample, all ranks are equally likely for each individual sample.